# VM forced to only look on local network

Tags: virtualbox, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm running a ***RedHat 6.7*** image on VBox. The previous configurations are forcing it to run requests through a gateway VM, which I don't have access to. Basically, when I try to install something, it will only look through 10.0.1.10 to see if the installation files are there (I think).

For instance, when installing `nmap`, I get the following error:

```
$ yum -y nmap
http://10.0.1.10/yum... [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 7 -
"couldn't connect to host"... [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try...
```

**Where can I find the configuration that forces the VM to only look for 10.0.1.10?**

---

VBox Network settings:

- Adapter 1: Host-only, Allow All, Cable Connected.
- Adapter 2: NAT, Cable Con, Port Forwarding: Host Port: 2222, Guest
  Port: 22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yum configurations are kept in **/etc/yum.repos.d/**.  Figure out which repo file has that address:

```
grep 10.0.1.10 /etc/yum.repos.d/*
```

Your next problem is where to point it to instead of that IP address.  If it's just a matter of changing the IP address, great, edit the repo file and replace it.

If not, you can mount the Red Hat 6.7 ISO image, and copy **media.repo** from the cd to /etc/yum.repos.d/, or follow instructions to create a repository somewhere else.

Comment: Ok, so I had another VM on here, but it had CentOS. On that instance, I installed a number of applications from different IPs. It seems like there is some configuration standing "in front" of the internet on this VM saying "you need to use 10.0.1.10 to find everything." Are you saying that's not the case, that the definitions of all these applications exist inside Linux, and it doesn't access some central "look-up" to find the IPs of where to download these things?

Comment: Do you have a Red Hat subscription?  It's really best to use it and pull things from the Internet if so.  But if not, then someone set up a local repository at 10.0.1.10 and configured a repo file to look their first.

Comment: The repository has the definitions for all the packages, probably the repository was at 10.0.1.10 but it is the repo file in /etc/yum.repos.d/ that points you in the direction of the repository.  Red Hat documents for subscription manager: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Subscription_Management/1/html/RHSM/entitlements-and-yum.html